# how to remove empty p tag and &nbsp from html in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-render-html

i want to remove empty p tag and &nbsp from dynamic html content.

below is html content retrieved from api response. empty p tag and &nbsp creates unwanted whitespace. i want to remove unwanted whitespace.

i am using react-native-render-html package to display the html content.

```
expo sdk : 38 
react-native-render-html : ~1.9.0 
platform : Android,Ios

<p> </p>
<p> &nbsp </p>
```

Comment: FYI, you seem to be using a extremely old version of react-native-render-html !

Answer (score 2):

Sanitizing the output in the server would be better but according to your question, you can use a RegExp like this:

```
/<p>(\s|(&nbsp))*<\/p>/gmi
```

Example:

```
var string = "<p>  &nbsp   &nbsp  </p>";
var pattern = /<p>(\s|(&nbsp))*<\/p>/gmi;
var result = str.match(patt);

if(result) {
     console.log("Pattern matched. Do not add the string to the html.")
}
```

Pattern explanation:

- The first `<p>` is the plain p element characters.
- `(\s|(&nbsp))*` tells that there would be char groups that contain
  spaces, or &nbsp character string. If you find those zero time or
  more, match them.
- Final `<\/p>` is the finishing p element. Inverted slash comes before
  the slash, because normal slash is a special character in RegExp. So
  we are escaping it with inverted slash.

Answer (score 1):

In **react-native-render-html** there is a option for ignoring tag.

```
import { IGNORED_TAGS } from 'react-native-render-html/src/HTMLUtils';
...
 
// your props
ignoredTags={[ ...IGNORED_TAGS, 'tag1', 'tag2']}
```

Comment: i don't want to remove whole p tags  but i have to remove only empty p tags and p tag containing &nbsp; 

<p>some text</p> ----- i don't want to remove this

<p></p>   ----- i want to remove this empty p tag
<p>&nbsp;</p> ----- i also want to remove this p tag

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression to remove html tags (except `&nbsp;`)

```
const regEx = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
const tempResult = yourData.replace(regEx, '');
```

If html response contains `&nbsp;` then follow additional step:

```
const secondRegEx = /((&nbsp;))*/gmi;
const result = tempResult.replace(secondRegEx, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have used it, It worked fantastically**

```
import HTMLView from 'react-native-htmlview';

htmlText = htmlText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '');

 <HTMLView
    stylesheet={htmlStyles}
    addLineBreaks={false}
    value={htmlText}
 />
```